# Why i can't load a script from apis.google.com?

Tags: python, pyside

Here is my code for test:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)

web.load(QUrl("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"))
web.show()

inspect = QWebInspector()
inspect.setPage(web.page())
inspect.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i try to load pages where included "apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" i get nothing, but in my browser all works fine. 
UPD: I use PySide-1.2.1.win32-py3.3 package from www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

because you need to install from http://qt-project.org/wiki/Get-PySide instead of www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs